# How to refresh the winforms designer

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

In one of my WinForms application, Looks the designer files are not updated. Suppose in design View I delete some controls, it is not reflecting in designer.cs.

Note: If i do any resizing action to the form, it wil updated properly .

Any suggestion?

Comment: The usual: Clean Solution, Rebuild Solution, exit VS, remove the hidden `.vs` Folder in the top-level Solution Directory, remove the `obj` Folder(s) in the Project(s) directory, open up VS again. Open Solution. Hope. -- Post the VS version in use.

Comment: And if that doesn't work, you might have to post your designer.cs file.